# QTabWidget get the tab page's widgets

Tags: qt5, qwidget, pyqt5, qtabwidget

So I'm using `PyQt5` to develop an app.

I'm able to create a new tab with a custom widget.

This widget had 3 other widgets in a custom layout, ie. a `QTextEdit`, a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton`.

I can get the `QWidget` for the current tab, by `tabWidget.currentWidget()` bt I don't understand how to get to that `QLineEdit` or any of the other widgets for that matter.

Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance :)